# R and SQL Server using Actual driver for Mac OS

Tags: sql-server, r, macos

I'm trying to connect RStudio on MacOS 10.12 to a SQL Server instance out on the network.

I tried installing RODBC via `install.packages("RODBC")`. This failed with the error:

```
configure: error: "ODBC headers sql.h and sqlext.h not found"
```

I understand Mac OS and RStudio use iODBC, but those headers are part of unixODBC, so I installed that via `brew install unixODBC`. That solved the RODBC install at least, and now I'm able to load that library successfully in RStudio via `library(RODBC)`.

Next I installed ODBC Manager from http://odbcmanager.net and the Actual SQL Server driver from Actual Technologies. I was then able to setup a DSN pointing at my local SQL Server, which looks like this in `/Library/ODBC/odbc.conf`:

```
[ODBC Data Sources]
sqlbox = Actual SQL Server

[sqlbox]
Driver         = /Library/ODBC/Actual SQL Server.bundle/Contents/MacOS/atsqlsrv.so
Description    = SQLBox
Server         = sqlbox.mydomain.com
UserID         = myuser
UseKeychain    = Yes
ServerName     = sqlbox
host           = sqlbox.mydomain.com
client charset = UTF-8
```

Now when I request a connection in R via `conn<-odbcDriverConnect("sqlbox")` I get this error:

```
Warning messages:
1: In odbcDriverConnect("sqlbox") :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state S1092, code 0, message [Actual][SQL Server] Invalid option
2: In odbcDriverConnect("sqlbox") : ODBC connection failed
```

Obviously it is finding the DSN, and loading (or at least finding) the Actual driver, but something is still off. The ODBC Manager tool does not have a Test button to validate a connection, so I can't try that. Is there another tool which would give better feedback on why the connection is failing? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the system DSN and recreating it as a user DSN (in `~/Library/ODBC/odbc.ini`) seems to have solved it. I'm now able to connect and pull SQL Server data from R.

Comment: Would you be able to show the step how to change the system DSN to user DSN ?